# How to load react component based on prop value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fluentui-react

I am using icon component  with '**@fluentui/react-northstar**' library as as below

```
import { QnaIcon } from '@fluentui/react-northstar'
const Example1 = () => (
  <>
    <QnaIcon size="large" />
  </>
)
```

Now I have to dynamically load the icon component when icon name is come from prop something  like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, TeamCreateIcon   } from '@fluentui/react-northstar' 

const Example2 = ({iconName}) => {
 
const MyIcon = <iconName /> ; //here I need to convert string to component 

return (
  <div >
     <Button icon={<TeamCreateIcon />} title="Create" />
     // Here I need set it
     <Button icon={<MyIcon />} title="Create" />    
  </div>
)}
```

```
<Example2 iconName='QnaIcon' />
```

[code https://codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/fluent-ui-example-forked-2xtbt?file=/example.js:277-286)

Comment: Can you pass the icon itself in props instead of just the icon name?

Comment: @squillman I have to  pass icon name from a json & it is configurable

Comment: I was just thinking that the other component could determine the icon since it's already determining which one you need.  Keep the logic in one place.  You can still parse the JSON in the other component to get the icon and pass it to this component.

Answer (score 2):

I am Brazilian and therefore I speak Portuguese, but I will use the translator to try to help you.

What you can do is the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, TeamCreateIcon   } from '@fluentui/react-northstar' 

const Example2 = ({iconName}) => {

const ICONS = {
  iconLike: <YourLikeIcon/>,
  iconMenu: <YourMenuIcon/>,
}

return (
  <div >
     <Button icon={<TeamCreateIcon />} title="Create" />
     // Here I need set it
     <Button icon={ICONS[iconName]} title="Create" />    
  </div>
)}
```

But you must be careful with `iconName`, because if it is not correct it can give an error. To prevent you can do some tests beforehand.

Comment: This is great. however in your scenario i have to add all  icons . i created sandbox demo   https://codesandbox.io/s/fluent-ui-example-forked-2xtbt?file=/example.js:277-286

Answer (score 1):

I would rather do it in a different way. I would pass the component itself as props to Example2

```
<Example2>
  <Icon/>
</Example2>
```

In the actual component, I would use props.children, which contains the child component that we mentioned as above

```
import React from 'react'

const Example2 = () => {
 

return (
  <div >
     <Button icon={props.children} title="Create" />
     <Button icon={<MyIcon />} title="Create" />    
  </div>
)}
```

**EDIT**

Including the codesandbox link as well

https://codesandbox.io/s/fluent-ui-example-forked-p5lkk?file=/example.js

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I was thinking in my comments on the question.

Comment: @squillman Yeah. IMO,  this is the best way to approach this problem

Comment: I am trying to digest this .. I created sandbox here. https://codesandbox.io/s/fluent-ui-example-forked-2xtbt?file=/example.js:277-286

Comment: @InfoÁsith Added a working codesandbox link in the answer. Please check

Comment: @Near Thank you for response.  I checked your sandbox URL, but I wanted to create icon component dynamically. here I created another sandbox to simplify the problem   
  https://codesandbox.io/s/fluent-ui-example-forked-rrk4l?file=/example.js

Comment: You can never use any icon without importing it into your file. So, there's no point in doing it dynamically without you importing the icon components in the file you want to use it

Comment: @Near . It has to do dynamically in my requirement. i was looking something similar like https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy